# How do you do multiple actions if-true in an AS_IF?

Tags: autotools, pkg-config

So, I'm working on overhauling a very old `configure.in` to a modern `configure.ac`, and I've come to a bit of a stumbling block.

I'm trying to use an `AS_IF` statement to do 1-3 things depending on the results from `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` and `AC_ARG_ENABLE`, but I can't seem to coerce them into the `AS_IF` action-if-true slot.

My current setup is as follows:

```
# Check for libbar
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([BAR],[bar],[bar_found=yes],[bar_found=no])
AC_ARG_ENABLE([bar],
    AS_HELP_STRING([--enable-bar],[enable support for bar [default=yes]]))
AS_IF([test x$enable_bar = xyes],
    [AS_IF(
        [test x$bar_found = xyes],
        [AC_DEFINE([HAVE_BAR_SUPPORT],[1],[Define if bar support is enabled])],
        [AC_MSG_ERROR([*** bar requested but not found ***])])
    ]
)
AS_IF([test x$enable_bar = xyes],
    [AS_IF(
        [test x$bar_found = xyes],
        [AX_APPEND_LINK_FLAGS([$BAR_LIBS],[LDFLAGS])],
        [AC_MSG_ERROR([*** bar requested but not found ***])])
    ]
)
AS_IF([test x$enable_bar = xyes],
    [AS_IF(
        [test x$bar_found = xyes],
        [AX_APPEND_COMPILE_FLAGS([$BAR_CFLAGS],[CFLAGS])],
        [AC_MSG_ERROR([*** bar requested but not found ***])])
    ]
)
```

So as you can see, it works, but it is overly verbose. I'd like to be able to handle all the action-if-true stuff in a single `AS_IF`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`AS_IF` is just an expansion for `if ...; then ...; else ...; fi`

So you can add as much code within the block as you want, as long as it's all separated by newlines:

```
AS_IF([test x$enable_bar = xyes], [
  AS_IF([test x$xbar_found], [
    AC_DEFINE(...)
    AX_APPEND_LINK_FLAGS(...)
    AX_APPEND_COMPILE_FLAGS(...)
  ], [
    AC_MSG_ERROR(...)
])
```

Comment: Many thanks, this is exactly what I needed syntactically and stylistically. Its tricky to format m4 in configure.ac in a way that is readable and doesn't look terrible, so props on that!